# Django - Get count of child objects associated with the Parent object

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to get the count of existing child objects associated with the Parent object.

I have a Parent Model like:

```
class ParentObj(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name', max_length=50)
```

Now I have these Child models.

```
class ChileObj1(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name', max_length=50)

class ChileObj2(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name', max_length=50)

class ChileObj3(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name', max_length=50)
```

Now it could be that there are only two child objects for the parent object, instead of 3.
How can get a count of them using a query.

TIA

Comment: Is the schema of these `ChileObj1`, `ChileObj2` the _exact_ same? If it is why not keep them as **one** model only?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat They are totally different.

Answer (score 1):

Annotate the counts of the child objects using the [`Count` function [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#id8) and then add them in another annotation.

```
from django.db.models import Count, F

queryset = ParentObj.objects.annotate(
    child1_count=Count('chileobj1', distinct=True),
    child2_count=Count('chileobj2', distinct=True),
    child3_count=Count('chileobj3', distinct=True),
).annotate(child_count=F('child1_count') + F('child2_count') + F('child3_count'))

for parent in queryset:
    print(parent.name, parent.child_count)
```

> **Note**: The `distinct=True` part is important here as this query would generate a join over **multiple tables** which can give
> inconsistent results with aggregations. This will work for `Count`
> but for other aggregations we would need to use subqueries to do such
> annotations.

Comment: I think, OP wants to do **group by**: `ParentObj.objects.values("id").annotate(...)`

Comment: @NKSM aggregation functions with related models perform a group by query automatically. Try `print(queryset.query)` to see the query that will be run for the queryset. This way we also have the extra benefit that we actually get the model instances from the queryset instead of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can make viewSet and iterate Parent model like:

```
querySet = Parent.objects.all()
```

and then create a def that return the count of each child